# Why is the mizbeach hazahav not mentioned in parshas terumah with the rest of the keilim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tetzaveh, mizbeach-altar

Do any of the meforshim comment on why the mizbeach hazahav (the golden altar) is mentioned in parshas tetzaveh which largely deals with the bigdei kehunah (the clothing of the kohanim) and not in the previous parsha (Terumah) which deals at length with all the keilim (vessels) used in the mishkan?

Comment: See Ramban on 30:1 for one approach